# Angular display own datas for each dynamic arrayForm

Tags: angular

I have a dynamics ng-select and input through an arrayForm.

HTML:

```js
<ng-container formArrayName="bottles">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="productContainer">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let bottle of getBottles.controls; let i=index">
            <div [formGroup]="bottle" style="display: flex">
              <label for="alias-{{ i }}">Produit:</label>
              <ng-select id="productInput" (change)='selectTest($event, i)'
                         [items]="test[0] | keyvalue" bindLabel="value.name" bindValue="value.quantity" formControlName="product"></ng-select>
              <label for="bottleQuantity">Bottles needed: </label>
              <input *ngFor="let bott of bottles" style="height: 26px" id="bottleQuantity" type="bottleQuantity" formControlName="bottleQuantity"/><div for="alias-{{ i }}" style="color: green" *ngIf="itemSelected">(Qty: {{itemSelected}})</div>
              <span class="material-icons" style="cursor:pointer; color: red" *ngIf="getBottles.controls.length > 1" type="button addClass" (click)="removeBottle(i)">delete</span>
            </div>
          </ng-container>
          <span class="material-icons" style="cursor:pointer; color: green" (click)="addBottlesInput()">add_circle</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
```

What i'd like is to display the own quantity of bottles for each dynamic field  using index. But i don't know how to perform this using index (or an easier way ? )

```js
<div for="alias-{{ i }}" style="color: green" *ngIf="itemSelected">(Qty: {{itemSelected}})</div>
```

See an example here [StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m15pdf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Thank you for help :)

Comment: your `index` is always 1. Check and correct your structure. Seems like a design problem

Comment: What do you want Qty to show? The total available number of bottles for the product? That is, if you select bottle1, then Qty should show 5?

Comment: I only want the « quantity » for each selected elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to show the quantity for the selected product per row:

1. Need an array to store the selected product.

```js
public itemsSelected: any[] = [];
```

2. When a new row is added, you need to add the empty object into `itemsSelected` array.

```js
public addBottlesInput = () => {
  ...

  this.itemsSelected.push({});
};
```

3. When selecting a product for each row, you need to update the object in `itemsSelected` by **index**.

```js
public selectTest = (event, i) => {
  if (event) {
    event.index = i;
    console.log('SELECTED', event);
    this.itemsSelected[i] = event.value;
  } else {
    this.itemsSelected[i] = {};
  }
};
```

4. Lastly, in HTML, you need to get the object from `itemsSelected` by index. Use `?.` (optional chaining) to *safe* get the quantity, especially for the case when the product is deselected.

```
<div style="color: green">
    (Qty: {{ itemsSelected[i]?.quantity }})
</div>
```

Or

```
<div style="color: green" *ngIf="itemsSelected[i]">
    (Qty: {{ itemsSelected[i].quantity }})
</div>
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tkfqkd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Works fine, that’s i what i wanted to do, thk you a lot ! :)